# Add parameter to function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// set Process
i18n.setProcess(function() {diFunctions.getI18n('http://localhost/service/i18n/page?lang=eng&group=staff') });

// Setter and getter 
this.setProcess = function( opProcess ) {  //here param opProcess is function with parameters see i18n.setProcess() line of code
        if( opProcess == undefined) 
            throw "Process is undefined";
        if( $.isFunction(opProcess) == false )
            throw "Process is not a function"
             process = opProcess;

    };
    this.getProcess = function() {
        return process;
    };
```

See how i18n.setProcess passes a function with param as a parameter to setProcess.

Now i what i want in SetProcess is `function() {diFunctions.getI18n('http://localhost/service/i18n/page?lang=eng&group=staff',**id**)` // id is added dynamically to the function itself which was passed as parameter  to setProcess

Problem - I want to add id dynamically(defined in my class variable always accesible by id) on set process with addition to functions parameter(Url,etc,etc,id). Functions parameters can grow but the id should be added last as a parameter?

Tried quite a few solutions but didnot work out? Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064800/dynamically-bind-argument-and-default-value-to-existing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: P.S i havent posted the code as its huge just posted what i wanted to do if thats why the downvote is

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object is for..

```
function foo() {
    var lastArg = arguments.length ? arguments[arguments.length - 1] : 'default';
    return lastArg;
}

foo();     // "default"
foo(1);    // 1
foo(1, 2); // 2
```

---

If you want to write a function similar to `bind` which only sticks arguments on the end then you could do

```
function appendArguments(fn) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice),
        args = slice(arguments, 1);
    return function () {
        return fn.apply(this, slice(arguments).concat(args));
    };
}
```

now

```
var bar = appendArguments(foo, 3);
bar();     // 3
bar(4, 5); // 3 (because it's calling `foo(4, 5, 3)`
```

Comment: arguments.length always gives 0 i tried it befroe posting it

Comment: @inputError you seem to be confusing `foo.length` with `arguments.length` inside `foo`.

Comment: but what my question is that when i assign opProcess to process. i havent call the process function yet . I want to add id to process function's parameter even before calling it

Comment: i can access argument object only inside from the function and not before that

Comment: @inputError please see edit, I think I understood you this time. The question is not clear, though.

Comment: appendArguments takes only fn as parameter. where is the second parameter?

Comment: it did not work. I am trying to add parameter to the process function itself and process function can have any number of paramaters so always add id to last but it does not return the function with appended id as parameter

Comment: What you want is really not clear. The function returned will have the last argument being what you entered. Please review the example I did for `foo` and notice how `bar` (a new function created from `foo`) acts as if it is `foo` but with a last parameter always being passed as `3` (in the example).

Comment: In your case, you would pass the `id` instead of `3`, then use the newly returned function

Comment: @Paul.S. see my updated question if you can get it this time ?